# Html.DropDownListFor field not displaying value from view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm rendering a view with a populated View Model. Visual Studio's Immediate window confirms that at the point of rendering, Title and Country have set values, yet only the Country value is correct. Title has reverted to the first SelectListItem value.

Switching the sources of the drop downs (both can use the same helper) make no difference, no matter which source I use the Title property always defaults back to the first item.

If I use @Html.TextBoxFor... instead, the value displays correctly. My question is more a plea for help - what can causesuch behaviour?

MyViewModel

```
public string Title {get; set;}
public string Country {get; set;}
```

View

```
...
ViewBag.Title = "Test"
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Title, CertificateFormHelpers.GenerateTitles(), new {@class = "form-select"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Country, Countries.All(), new { @class = "form-select" })
```

**Update**: The View had a conflicting property name. Updated view to include this declaration.

Comment: If the first option is selected, it means that the value of `Title` does not match exactly one of the option values

Comment: Indeed that was my understanding. But if I simply switch the helpers, still, Title does not work despite the value matching. It definitely matches.

Comment: What do you mean _if I simply switch the helpers_? And no they do not match. If the value of `Title` is `"abc"` and one of the options your generating has `value="abc"` it will be selected

Comment: If Title uses Countries.All and I select an item, still the value resets to the first in the list. The value = "Miss" and in the immediate window the property on Model.Title == "Miss". It still resets.

Comment: Sorry, but your not making sense.

Comment: Ok. If each of those properties was populated by the same SelectList collection, and if say I chose the same drop down value for each, still, Title would revert to the first item in the list.

Comment: Viewbag.Title was being used - it conflicted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is more a plea for help - what can cause such behaviour?

In this particular case, the ViewBag had a property called 'Title' and my model also had a 'Title' property. The value of the ViewBag.Title didn't exist in the collection being used to populate the dropdown options, hence why the dropdown defaulted to the first item in that collection.